# PHP - shell_exec grep, Not working with variable

Tags: php, grep, shell-exec

I have the following PHP snippet that will pull an IP out of a Curl verbose response and assign the output to a variable(This works perfectly):

```
$ipss = shell_exec("grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' curllog/10-08-2013_114304am.txt|head -1");
```

The issue I am having is I am trying to make the file it searches for dynamic, but it returns nothing:

```
 $ipss = shell_exec("grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' curllog/$curlfile|head -1");
```

When I echo out the $curlfile it shows the correct file name.

I have another shell_exec that uses a variable and it works fine:

```
shell_exec("wkhtmltoimage --crop-h 1080 --crop-w 1200 --load-error-handling ignore --quality 10 tmp/$htmlname tmp/$imagename");
```

I am not able to see why the grep with a variable is not working. Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's the current filename ($curlfile)?

Comment: 10-08-2013_114329am.txt  if I manually input  that instead of the variable im trying to use it works flawlessly.

Comment: Show us the echo out of: echo "grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' curllog/$curlfile|head -1";

Comment: grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' curllog/10-08-2013_121004pm.txt|head -1

Comment: @Jeremy That's another date? and btw. are you sure that the file already exists at script execution time? and not only after script?

Comment: yeah, I am running my script every time I test so it generates a brand new file. I close my file before I do the actual grep, I figured this would create it before I greped it. Is there another way to make sure my file is created before my next php script runs?